# Puppet: Run Augeas only when a specific package exists

Tags: puppet, packages, augeas

I want to use Augeas to modify "/etc/inittab", but this should only happen when the package "sysvinit" is installed. That package is not under Puppet control (and shall not be).

The "onlyif" from Augeas doesn´t seem capable of checking for anything else than Augeas stuff, i.d. Augeas cannot check if file exists.

Is there a way to achieve this without creating a custom fact?

Comment: You might be to a point where you are just going to have make yourself a custom fact that tells you if sysvinit is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an [Augeas provider](http://www.augeasproviders.com) and [confine it](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/provider_development.html#suitability) to [a fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) which checks for the package's presence.

To sum  it up:

- Write a `sysvinit_package` fact, with value `true` or `false` (or even the package version)
- Write a type and provider for `inittab` which is confined to the fact.

Note: the `augeasproviders` API is being redone to easily create providers outside of the `augeasproviders` module. See [the shellvar standalone provider](https://github.com/raphink/augeasprovider-shellvar) (PoC for now, the API will probably work this way eventually) for example.

Alternatively, if you just want to use the `augeas` type instead of writing a provider (which I would recommend though), you can just write a fact and use it in Puppet DSL to avoid declaring the `augeas` resource when `sysvinit` is not installed.

Comment: Probably the best solution, therefore I have marked this as the solution. However, with my basic knowledge I won't try to do it, cause writing a simple lens has already been a pita ;-)

Comment: I like to believe that writing Augeas providers is easier than writing lenses.

Answer (score 1):

A horrible alternative would be to ditch the `augeas` resource type for an `exec` resource running `augtool`, and checking for the package in an `onlyif` command.

I'd go with the custom fact.